# mysql sum and group by giving wrong results

Tags: mysql

I am using following tables...

```
stats (id, game, user_id, rank, score, dnt)
teams(id, name, dnt)
users(id, username, email, team_id, dnt)
```

I want to grab top 10 high scorer teams based on stats(team total score gets calculated on total score by its users)

sample data for stats...

```
| id | game | user_id | rank | score | dnt |
+----+------+---------+-------+------+-----+
|  1 | test | 5       | 2    | 2200  | 
+--------+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|  2 | test | 3       | 1    | 2500  | 
+--------+----------+----------+-----+-----+
```

teams

```
| id | name  | dnt |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | team1 |     |
+----+-------+-----+
|  2 | team2 |     |
+----+-------+-----+
```

users

```
| id | username | email | team_id |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
|  1 | user1    |       | 1       |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
|  1 | user2    |       | 2       |
+----+----------+-------+---------+
```

And i am trying following sql query...

```
SELECT t.name as team_name, sum(s.score) as total_score 
        FROM teams t 
        JOIN users u ON u.team_id = t.id
        JOIN stats s ON s.user_id = u.id
        GROUP BY team_name ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

But above query is returning 0 rows, even i want your help tp write up top 10 users score.

Thanks for help.

Comment: sample data for other tables please.

Comment: @cularis more sample data added. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user_id` in `stats` table is nowhere to be found in your `users` table. You even have 2 users with the same `id`? Your query returns the correct result.

```
SELECT t.name as team_name, sum(s.score) as total_score 
FROM teams t 
INNER JOIN users u 
  ON u.team_id = t.id
INNER JOIN stats s 
  ON s.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY team_name 
ORDER BY total_score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: thanks can you help me with how can we get top 10 users with high score.

Comment: There you go. Obviously only works if you have correct data in your table.

Comment: should i update GROUP BY team_name with u.user_name to get top 10 high scorers users?

Comment: IF you want users, you have to group by u.username and select u.username instead of t.name.